# Inverse of $(1+x)^{2^n+1}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^{2^n+1})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

It need to prove that the coefficient of order $2^n-1$ of the inverse of the polynomial $(1+x)^{2^n+1}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^{2^n+1})$ is not $0$. It's possible calculate the complete inverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On $\mathbb Z_2[X]$, since the polynomial has coefficients in $\mathbb Z_2$, the identity
$$ (1+x)^{2^n +1} = (1+x)(1+x)^{2^n} = (1+x)(1+x^{2^n}) = 1 + x + x^{2^n} + x^{2^n+1}$$
holds (thanks to the Frobenius morphism). Over $\mathbb Z_2[X]/(x^{2^n+1})$, this identity becomes
$$(1+x)^{2^n+1} = 1 + x + x^{2^n}. $$
Then, notice that (still in $\mathbb Z_2[X]/(x^{2^n+1})$),
\begin{align*}(1+x+x^2 + \cdots + x^{2^{n-1}}) (1 + x + x^{2^n}) &=  (1+x+x^2 + \cdots + x^{2^{n-1}}) \\ &+ x(1+x+x^2 + \cdots + x^{2^{n-1}})\\ &+ x^{2^n}(1+x+x^2 + \cdots + x^{2^{n-1}})\\
 &= 1+2(x+x^2 + \cdots + x^{2^{n-1}}) + 2x^{2^n} = 1.
\end{align*}
(match the powers of $x$ in $(1+x+x^2 + \cdots + x^{2^{n-1}})$ and $x(1+x+x^2 + \cdots + x^{2^{n-1}})$).

Comment: Thanks, Milnor ensure this without proof for show that projective spaces of dimension $2^n$ can't be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{2\times2^n-1}$ through characteristic classes :)

Comment: @Ludwik thank you for context !

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Its inverse is $(1+x+\cdots+x^{2^n})^{2^n+1}$.

Indeed, if $a$ is an inverse of $(1+x)$, then $a^k$ is an inverse of $(1+x)^k$.

Now, taking into account that $2=0$ and that we work in $\mathbb{Z}_2/(x^{2^n+1})$, we have
$(1+x+\cdots+x^{2^n})(1+x)=1+x^{2^n+1}=1$.

Comment: Thanks, only one more thing, from this $(1+x+\cdots+x^{2^n})^{2^n+1}$ I can ensure that the coefficient of order $2^n-1$ is not $0$?